# SPFX sharepoint Deployment

Tags: spfx

i have deployed spfx to sharepoint online. firsts I have run gulp bundle --ship and   again gulp package-solution --ship. I have uploaded bundle file to site assets mentioned path in manifest file. package file I have uploaded to app catalog.

now if I have to modify existing code should I again run two commands and upload files back? I see bundle files generate file name with different version name.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct from my experience.

The bundle files have a hash appended to them based on their contents, to differentiate between two versions of the script. This make it easier for browsers to get new versions when they are available. Waldek wrote [a nice brief explanation](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/5-differences-sharepoint-framework-debug-release-builds/#filenamesinreleasebuildcontainhash) about why they do this.

Note that when you upload the new package file, any pages with your web part(s) will *immediately* start pointing towards the *new* version of the bundle files. For best experience, I recommend uploading the bundle files first, then the package file, to avoid users experiencing any web part errors for that short duration if you uploaded them the other way around.

Comment: can we remove serial number in bundle files and upload. should we uplod both package and bundle file whenever we do chnges?

Comment: You can remove the hash from the bundle files, but you have to do it **after** running `bundle` but **before** running `package-solution`, otherwise the package will be expecting bundle files with the hash and complain when it can't find them. To your 2nd question, yes, you should do both.

Comment: Edit: **Actually, it does not appear possible** to remove the hash this way! I tried loading a web part after doing this, and it was still requesting the hashed version of the script files. If you really want to remove the hash (again, there's good reason why they add it) you might check if [this method](http://kwizcom.blogspot.com/2017/10/removing-hash-from-spfx-bundle-file-name.html) still works.

Comment: because we have another spfx project where whenever we do any changes to code we just upload bundle file by removing hash. we do not upload package in catalog. its just one time they have upload. we always modify code and gulp --ship uopload bundle file dats. I just wanted to know how to achieve it. I could not find any sources

Comment: this project was developed by microsoft. not sure how how they did this way

Comment: I see how that would be useful. Please see if [this article](http://kwizcom.blogspot.com/2017/10/removing-hash-from-spfx-bundle-file-name.html) works for you. Same article as I linked in my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can add "includeClientSideAssets": true" to your package-solution.json file, and you don't need to manually deploy your assets. You need just deploy .sppkg package and that's it. 
You can even deploy it using o365 cli from cmd. In our env I created gulp task that first modify current version and then boundle and deploy it.

includeClientSideAssets attribute was introduced in the SPFx v1.4

Answer (score 0):

Every time we modify / add any changes , we should run both gulp bundle --ship, gulp package-solution --ship commands and deploy the .sppkg package